# Laravel: Iterate over object array

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, iteration, laravel-blade

Ok, so I have an array of objects created in my controller

```
$displayRooms[$room] = $this->getNextEvent($events, $room);

return view('schedule')->with(['displayRooms' => $displayRooms]);
```

Then in my view, I am able to iterate over the array and get the $room and $events

```
@foreach ($displayRooms as $room => $events)
    {{ var_dump($events) }}
@endforeach
```

The var_dump($events) produces

```
/home/vagrant/sites/google-cal/storage/framework/views/96faa8d8afe2e0f07db5d96a536009499a3c48a5.php:22:
object(stdClass)[176]
  public 'available' => boolean false
  public 'room' => string 'Room 318' (length=8)
  public 'summary' => string 'Chem 3090 Himmeldirk' (length=20)
  public 'startTime' => string '12:00pm' (length=7)
  public 'endTime' => string '3:00pm' (length=6)
  public 'startDay' => string '03/21/17' (length=8)
  public 'endDay' => string '03/21/17' (length=8)

/home/vagrant/sites/google-cal/storage/framework/views/96faa8d8afe2e0f07db5d96a536009499a3c48a5.php:22:null

/home/vagrant/sites/google-cal/storage/framework/views/96faa8d8afe2e0f07db5d96a536009499a3c48a5.php:22:null

/home/vagrant/sites/google-cal/storage/framework/views/96faa8d8afe2e0f07db5d96a536009499a3c48a5.php:22:
object(stdClass)[226]
  public 'available' => boolean false
  public 'room' => string 'Room 513 (Voinovich Room)' (length=25)
  public 'summary' => string 'Reynolds' (length=8)
  public 'startTime' => string '1:00pm' (length=6)
  public 'endTime' => string '3:00pm' (length=6)
  public 'startDay' => string '03/21/17' (length=8)
  public 'endDay' => string '03/21/17' (length=8)
```

My question is how can I iterate over the events object in Blade in order to access the properties of the object, so that I may pass them to a partial view?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you are asking (and your data structure) properly, then this should work. You can iterate the array of event objects to access each one individually, and then iterate each individual one to access each individual property / value. This code should be nested within your first foreach (replace the dump with it).

```
@foreach($events as $event) 
    @foreach ($event as $prop => $value) 
        // do whatever with prop / values
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you don't need to access each property / value of the object one at a time, then I would recommend this instead.

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    // do whatever with each event
    {{ var_dump($event->available) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Received this error message:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you sure that you nested the foreach within your existing one? Can you paste the exact code that you are running when it errors?

Comment: `@foreach ($displayRooms as $room => $events)
    @foreach($events as $event) 
        @foreach ($event as $prop => $value) 
             {{ var_dump($value) }}
         @endforeach
     @endforeach
@endforeach`

Comment: Is $events not an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, But I think that it might be erroring out whenever it hits the 1st array that is null. See above paste of the var_dump()

Comment: i can do this 

`{{ var_dump($displayRooms[$room]->available) }}`

And it will give me the desired value that I want, but I can't replicate it in the partial view when I pass it to the partial using

`@each('partials.event', $displayRooms, 'event')`

Comment: Ah, alright. What you need to do then is inside the second loop (that is iterating $events) is add `@if (isset($event)) // do stuff @endif`.